# Dos attack in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: webserver, ubuntu-12.04, tomcat6, ddos

I am using ubuntu 12.04 server 64bit .I got mail from vendor ur server is attacked with Dos Attack .

My question how to find out the Dos attack

I Using Apache tomcat 6.0.42 web server and ssl certificate also.

can many help

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the requests in the apache access.log

Comment: we are redirecting traffic from 8080 to 80  so there is no access.log